Using Jenkins pipeline configuration area to run separate jobs
I am rewriting my testing scripts. I have a main core code pipeline which runs three types of builds. When it passes successfully about 25 other projects run to see if changes to the main code effects their code. This code is usually launched by a commit to the code repository of the production code.

Then I have a separate pipeline area where programmers can run pretest to see what tests or projects break. It goes through the same tests as the production pipelines but just generate results. The programmer starts these tests.
So my issue is that I have people add/change flight test pipelines to the production area and forget to add/change the pretest area. This has become a frequent annoying problem as people commit code to production and break projects.
I considered having the pretest just launch from the production with a check box to pass a parameter it is debug version. That will not work as I do not want flight projects to see a failed run and think their project failed especially when they are in lock down. Also, they do not have the same steps. Below is a broken pretest example then a picture of a production pipeline.


So has someone found a way to either read the pipeline area on Jenkins for projects and pass it to a new job area. Or maybe detect with a pipeline area has changed then I could update the pretest pipelines. Any suggested would be appreciated.


"This has become a frequent annoying problem as people commit code to production and break projects." - sounds like an incorrect setup of the SDLC processes, how is it possible? Also, I'm not sure I understand what do you call an "area", could you please elaborate on this?

